# pip cannot install anything. WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: ssh, pip

I have just set up my new raspberry system. However, my pip cannot install anything. Keep showing 'WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however, the SSL module in Python is not available.' and 'Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.'

This makes me unable to do anything right now. I wonder if someone knows how to figure this out? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use pip3 instead of pip? Pip is for Python 2.x  and is no longer supported.

Comment: your question is not about Raspberry Pi ... it is about python and linux

Comment: what o/s are running? desktop or headless? 64 bit or 32 bit? bullseye or buster? Have you ran an update/upgrade?

Comment: Also what do you get if you run pip --version and pip3 --version

Comment: You need to run `sudo pip3 install numpy` to make the package available for ALL python3 users.

Comment: DO NOT paste illegible pictures of text - paste text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `pip` run

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```

Comment: That only works for numpy, and doesn't install the package in custom-built Python versions.